# Como armazenar mais de um valor em uma "variável SQL"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, variáveis, relatório

Trabalho com um sistema que possui um report builder bastante limitado. Os relatórios, basicamente são restritos a **uma** consulta SQL.

Preciso apresentar em um relatório uma query que, em minha consulta, está sendo informado pelo usuário um parâmetro de multi-seleção, irei explicar melhor:

O usuário informa sobre quais unidades quer visualizar o relatório, imaginem que ele selecione as unidades 1 e 2, então na clausula `IN` ficará:

```
Where CODIGO_UNIDADE In (1,2)
```

Até aí tudo perfeito, o problema é que preciso apresentar no relatório quais unidades o usuário informou nos parâmetros, e, a única maneira que tenho de fazer isso é declarando variável no SQL e capturando o parâmetro que o usuário informou:

```
DECLARE @UNIDADE VARCHAR (100)

Set @UNIDADE = (

Select NOME from UNIDADES

Where CODIGO_UNIDADE In (:UNIDADE_INFORMADA_PELO_USUÁRIO)

)

Select @Unidade As 'Unidade Informada'
```

Como vocês já devem estar imaginando, isso não pode ser feito, pois, como a subquery retorna mais de um valor é retornado um erro:

```
Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 3
A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.
```

Qual a maneira mais fácil de se fazer isso? Considerando as limitações (passar o valor para uma variável) que possuo em meu report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a instrução `FOR XML`:

```
DECLARE @UNIDADE VARCHAR(100) = ''

set @UNIDADE =
(
    select  NOME + ','
    from    UNIDADES 
    Where   CODIGO_UNIDADE In (:UNIDADE_INFORMADA_PELO_USUÁRIO)
     for xml path('')
)

set @unidade = Left(@unidade, Len(@unidade) - 1)

select @unidade as 'Unidade(s) Informada(s)'
```

Adicionei o `Left` para retirar a vírgula.

Comment: Boa noite Vanderlei, obrigado por sua resposta! Essa solução funcionou perfeitamente e nem passou pela minha cabeça! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, amigo! 
Acredito que a forma mais fácil de fazer isso seja utilizando concatenação de string. Abaixo um exemplo aplicando na sua necessidade:

```
DECLARE @UNIDADE VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT @UNIDADE += UNIDADE + ', ' FROM UNIDADES WHERE CODIGO_UNIDADE IN (/* Códigos 
informados*/)

SELECT @UNIDADE AS 'Unidades Selecionadas'
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, obrigado por sua resposta! Essa solução não atendeu pois estava trazendo um registro para cada unidade.

Comment: Olá! Acredito que não. O script retorna somente 1 linha, independente do número de registros retornados, uma vez que estamos concatenando o retorno. Acabei de testar novamente e está correto. Pode dar uma olhada de novo? Editei a resposta retirando @ da UNIDADE da concatenação. Talvez isso tenha causado algum tipo de confusão. Espero ter ajudado. :D

Answer (score 1):

Otávio, avalie se o Report Builder aceita a seguinte construção:

```
-- código #1
declare @tbUnidade table (Deno_Unidade ___);

INSERT into @tbUnidade (Deno_Unidade)
  SELECT NOME 
    from UNIDADES
    where CODIGO_UNIDADE in (:parametro);
```

A coluna Deno_Unidade deve ser declarada com o mesmo tipo de dados da coluna NOME.

A forma acima é útil caso necessite manter separadas as denominações das unidades.

Comment: Boa tarde José, muito obrigado por sua resposta! O report não aceita comandos DML (INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE).

Comment: @OtávioAugusto Ok. Talvez o `INSERT` possa ser trocado por `SELECT ... into ...`, gerando uma tabela temporária. Mas não sei se o RB aceita. De qualquer forma, foi bom saber que encontrou a solução.